# If $d_f (t) : (0, \infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ prove $d_f (t) \leq \bigg( \frac{||{f}||_{L^p(X)}}{t} \bigg)^p.$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $1  \leq p < \infty$ and suppose that $f \in L^{p}(X).$ Define the function $d_f (t) : (0, \infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ by $$d_f(t)= \mu (\{ x \in X : |f(x)|>t\}).$$
  For each $t>0,$ prove that 
  $$d_f (t) \leq \bigg( \frac{||{f}||_{L^p(X)}}{t} \bigg)^p.$$

I'm stomped   by this problem, I don't even know where to begin. Could someone help me begin to understand this problem?

Comment: It's a classic, called the Markov inequality or the Chebyshev inequality. Start from the obvious fact that $$\int_X |f|^p\, d\mu \ge \int_{\{|f|>t\}} |f|^p\, d\mu.$$ P.S.: I love your avatar of Dr Manhattan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $$\|f\|_p^p =\underbrace{\int_{[|f|\leq t]}|f|^p}_{\geq 0}+\int_{[|f|>t]}|f|^p  \geq t^p d_f(t).$$Rearrange.